# delegate/live/on not working with ajax request

Tags: jquery, delegates

Here is my senario,

I have a textarea with an argument data-cancellation_confirmation.
This value is checked for disabling a checkbox. On click event of another button I changed the value of data-cancellation_confirmation. But when I tried to fetch the value again I can't find the update that I have done.

I have tried delegate of *jquery [version jquery-1.6.4]*.

**Code used =>**

In click function in jquery

```
jQuery("#booking_ticket_table").delegate('.agent_ticket_cancel', "click" , function() {
```

......
   value is read from textarea in jquery.

```
 var cancellation_confirmation = jQuery(this).data('cancellation_confirmation');
```

Checked in firebug the atribute is getting updated. but can't have it in jquery.

PS: Since its a maintenance project I have limitations alerting the code.

Any help ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made a change in fetching values.

changed

```
var cancellation_confirmation = jQuery(this).data('cancellation_confirmation');
```

with

```
var cancellation_confirmation = jQuery(this).attr('data-cancellation_confirmation');
```

This works.. can anyone have any inputs on this???